# 'out of breath' v.s 'breathless'

Tags: difference, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between **out of breath** and **breathless**?

I have read the dictionary carefully. I saw an example is that:

> We were **out of breath** after only five minutes.

And 'out of breath' is used with the meaning **having the difficulty breathing after exercise**.

I wonder if we can use **breathless** instead of **out of breath** in that case ?

Comment: You're simply substituting *out of breath* by the adjective *breathless.*

Comment: Out of breath -- shortness of breath from physical exertion.  Breathless, most often, not taking a breath because of excitement or fear; less often "out of breath".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Out of breath** is the result of *usually* a physical action.
**Breathless** is a condition.

Both mean to be **short of breath** and people will generally understand them to be interchangeable, however

> The children were **breathless** in anticipation.
>   After running we were **out of breath**

> When you are **out of breath** you are left **breathless**.
>   When you are **breathless** you are not necessary **out of breath**.